# I'm using woodmart theme , after activating shiprocket plugin the add to cart button is not working in worpress

Tags: wordpress, themes, shiprocket

I'm using woodmart theme , also i'm using latest version of worpress and plugins i have already checked by removing plugins i found that the after deactivating the shiprocket plugin the button is working , help me out in this problem

My expectation is after integrate the shiprocket with website, The functionality of add to cart button will not change

Comment: Contact plugin / theme authors for solution.  With this amount of info cant get much of help here unless providing some errors to point you where the problem may be.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.